# Create a responsive React application that shows a list of cards in a container

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to create a responsive React application using JavaScript that will show a list of cards on the page as pictured below. I'm fairly new to React and am not really sure where to begin with the layout. Currently, I have created a few reusable components for each portion of the app that I believe need to be added. These are the main container that will house every other component, the toolbar, sidebar, main card container that will house the cards in the center, and the footer. I'm not even sure if I need the main container component, maybe I can just use divs to house all the other components? Any tips? I can clarify and provide more details if needed. Thank you.

[image: Responsive React App showing a list of cards in a container.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use css `flex` with `inline-block`,

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import "./style.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="rowA col-md-4">
        <div>A</div>
        <div>B</div>
      </div>
      <div className="rowA clom-md-4">
        <div>C</div>
        <div>D</div>
      </div>
      <div className="rowA">
        <div>E</div>
        <div>F</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

styles.css

```
.rowA {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
}

.rowA div {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
```

my code for same design layout,
i used `reactstrap` for desgning,
[Application code found here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-bmpkwf?file=src/App.js)

```
import React from "react";
import "./style.css";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";

import {
  Card,
  CardImg,
  CardText,
  CardBody,
  CardTitle,
  CardSubtitle,
  Button,
  CardGroup,
  CardBody,
  CardImg,
  Container,
  Row,
  Col,
  CardFooter,
  CardDeck
} from "reactstrap";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Container>
        <Row className="show-border">
          <Col xs="8">
            <Row>
              <Col xs="6">
                <Button variant="light">Add Card</Button>
              </Col>
              <Col xs="6">
                <Button variant="light">Sort Card</Button>
              </Col>
            </Row>

            <CardDeck className="show-border">
              <Card>
                <CardTitle>Title</CardTitle>
                <CardText>This content is a little bit longer.</CardText>
                <CardBody />
                <CardFooter>
                  <small className="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small>
                </CardFooter>
              </Card>
              <Card>
                <CardTitle>Title</CardTitle>
                <CardText>This content is a little bit longer.</CardText>
                <CardBody />
                <CardFooter>
                  <small className="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small>
                </CardFooter>
              </Card>
            </CardDeck>
          </Col>
          <Col className="show-border" xs="4">
            (Instructions...)
          </Col>
        </Row>

        <Row className="show-border">
          <Col xs="6">Footer</Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
}
```